# Isomorphism of affine algebraic variety

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2886099/884739
Can Someone please explain why over the ground field $\mathbb{C}$ the above affine variety is isomorphic to $\{(z_1,z_2):z_1z_2\ne0\}$? What is the change of variable that you do?

if you write $x^2+y^2=(x+iy)(x-iy)$ then can you simply replace $(x+iy)$ by $z_1$ and $(x-iy)$ by $z_2$? because $x-iy$ is conjugate of $x+iy$, so they are not really independent variables.

Comment: What? You can absolutely do that. Where are you getting this idea from?

Comment: @HankScorpio Can you please elaborate how? as I said, they are not independent variables(they are conjugate of each other). Replacing them simply by $z_1$ and $z_2$ would mean they are independent.

Comment: They are absolutely independent variables! What the heck are you talking about?

Comment: $x-iy$ is not the complex conjugate of $x+iy$, because $x,y$ are complex numbers. Just let $z_1=x+iy,z_2=x-iy$ and check that you can recover $x,y$ from a linear map in $z_1,z_2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is (as indicated in the comments) a ring isomorphism (an isomorphism of $\mathbb{C}$-algebras):

$$ \phi: A_1:=\mathbb{C}[u,v]/(uv) \cong \mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2):=A_2$$

defined by $\phi(u):=x+iy, \phi(v):=x-iy$. The inverse ring isomorphism is

$$\phi^{-1}(x)=1/2(u+v), \phi^{-1}(y)=1/2i(u-v).$$

Hence we get an ismorphism of affine schemes (over $\mathbb{C}$):

$$f:Spec(A_1) \cong Spec(A_2).$$

**Question:** "Can Someone please explain why over the ground field C the above affine variety is isomorphic to ${(z1,z2):z1z2≠0}$? What is the change of variable that you do?"

**Answer:** The variable change given above induce an isomorphism $f$ of affine schemes. You may check that the above definition gives the inverse.
There are structure maps $\pi_i: Spec(A_i) \rightarrow Spec(\mathbb{C})$
and the isomorphism $f$ commute with these maps: $\pi_2 \circ f =\pi_1$.